# 大学教員の公募にでる「単行本」の意味

Tags: meaning, academic-japanese

## Japanese

一般的に、「単行本」という単語は連載している漫画の数章分をまとめて、本として、出版するものですが、大学教員の募集に

> 3)論文2編（主論文1編と参考論文1編とし、その別を必ず明記する。刊行された論文であること。単行本、修士論文、博士論文は不可。論文はコピーでも可。）

と書いてありました。修士論文と博士論文の意味はわかりますが、単行本はこの場面で、どのような意味になりますか。それは複数著者が一章ずつを書くものですか。また、他のものを表しているのですか。

## English

Normally *tankobon* refers to a published volume from a manga that appears in a weekly, but I saw the following sentence in a job application for a university position:

> 3)論文2編（主論文1編と参考論文1編とし、その別を必ず明記する。刊行された論文であること。単行本、修士論文、博士論文は不可。論文はコピーでも可。）

I understand they are saying no MA or PhD theses, but I'm not grasping what they mean here by "tankobon". Does it mean a book with chapters written by different authors published together or is it referring to something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

学術分野ですので、基本的には「ジャーナルに掲載された論文ではなく、最初から書籍や冊子の形で発表されたもの」という理解でよいと思います。この基準は特に、自費出版による論文集・研究書・エッセイ集のような、正当な査読を経ていない出版物を除外するためのものでしょう。主に単著の書籍を指しているのだと思いますが、共著の教科書のようなものも単行本です。具体的には[こういうもの](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worlds_in_Collision)や[こういうもの](https://books.google.com/books/about/?id=N1Gcfdj81T4C)が、学術的業績とは認められない「単行本」の例だと思います。

一般的には、新聞で連載された小説をまとめたものや、最初から本の形で出版するために書かれたもの（書き下ろし）も単行本の一種です。例えば「ハリー・ポッターと賢者の石」は（書き下ろしの）単行本と言えます。